# Basic question about discrete minimal surfaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex polygon with $n > 3$ vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $x$ be a point in the interior of $P$, and let $u$ be a function with prescribed values at the vertices of $P$, $u( v_{i} ) = u_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Assume that the points $( v_{i}, u_{i} ) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ are not coplanar. For what value of $u(x)$ does the (piecewise linear) graph of $u$ over $P$ have minimal area? How does the solution relate to the geometric median of the points $( v_{i}, u_{i} )$?

Answer (score 2):

For any interior edge of your area minimizing surface the sum of all 4 adjusted angles has to be at least $\pi$. Check my paper ["Area minimizing polyhedral surfaces are saddle"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3739) (Sorry for self-advertizement.)

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks:

(1) One interpretation of what is meant by "the (piecewise linear) graph of $u$ over $P$" is a triangulation of the 3D polygon determined by $(v_i,u_i)$.

(2) In general, determining whether or not a 3D polygon has a triangulation (not all 3D polygons are triangulable) is NP-hard. Your class is restricted in that its projection
to 2D is a convex polygon. And all your polygons are triangulable, e.g., by triangulating in 2D and lifting to 3D.

(3) If self-intersections among the triangles are permitted, then there is an $O(n^4)$ algorithm to find a triangulation that minimizes the sum of triangle areas.

(4) There are practical algorithms implemented, e.g.,

> Zou, Ming, Tao Ju, and Nathan Carr. "Delaunay-restricted Optimal Triangulation of 3D Polygons." (2012). ([PDF download](http://cse.wustl.edu/Research/Lists/Technical%20Reports/Attachments/993/pringleSGP.pdf).)

This relatively recent paper summarizes much of the earlier literature.

---

[image: MinAreaSaddle]

                  

<sup>(Fig.9 detail from Zou & Carr.)</sup>

---

Comment: An alternate phrasing of the problem a la remark (2): Given a 2D triangulation of a convex polygon with one interior point and a lift of its boundary into \mathbb{R}^3, where should the interior point go so as to minimize surface area? Convexity and having only one interior point simplify the problem considerably; there will be no intersections, for example. My main question is how the solution relates to geometric medians.